# ViewChild ng2 set content not working in internet explorer

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to change text area height according to its content height.
The textarea control is displayed when a 'Edit' button is pressed.

`@ViewChild` does not recognize the element because it does not exist in DOM when the component initialized.

Using `set content` fix this problem but it only works on chrome. Internet explorer not support it.

My code:

```
<ng-containter *ngIf="isEdit">
   <textarea #text formControlName="text"></textArea>
</ng-Containter>
```

.
.
.

```
private text:ElementRef
@ViewChild('text') set content(content:ElementRef){
   this.text = content;
   if (this.text){
       this.text.nativeElement.style.height = (this.text.nativeElement.scrollHeight) + "px";
   }
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be make use of lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit`. It's called once component is finished with rendering html template, but only once. [Here you can read more](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

#### *.component.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild('text') text: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.text) {
         this.text.nativeElement.style.height = (this.text.nativeElement.scrollHeight) + "px";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `AfterviewChecked` works properly  in internet explorer! Thanks :)